# How to extract attributes from HTML and update them in the database?

Tags: php, html

I have an `HTML code` shown below from which I want to extract attributes such as `coords`, the value of `id in href`, and `alt`. The `HTML code` is located inside the world directory. The following attributes are present in the `HTML code` below:

```
<map id="qmap" name="qmap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="430,255,665,304" href="abc.php?qmap=Good World&id=%25SSP%2550469%25" onclick="if( parent.document.body.rows == '*,0' ) parent.document.body.rows = '25%,75%'" alt="SSP 50469" target="content" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="457,97,691,116" href="abc.php?qmap=Good World&id=%25SSP%2541175-02%25" onclick="if( parent.document.body.rows == '*,0' ) parent.document.body.rows = '25%,75%'" alt="SSP 41175 Bk 2" target="content" />
</map>
```

After extracting these attributes, I want to update the `content` column in the `hello_world` table.

**This is what I have tried so far:**

I added `Line A` to the PHP code below, but more changes need to be made at `Line B`.

```
if (condition) {
    $html = file_get_contents('files/world/'.$world.'.html'); // Line A
    // parse the HTML, extract the data, and update the database with the information found in the HTML file (Line B)
}
```

The database update can be done in the following way:

```
$db->query("UPDATE `hello_world` SET `content` = '' WHERE `id` = '$file_id'");
```

Comment: `Line B` sounds like it describes a reasonable high-level description of an approach.  What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?  (As an aside... Your database query implies the potential of a SQL injection problem.  Now would be a good time to start looking into prepared statements with query parameters.)

Comment: You can extract the data very simple with DOMDocument. https://3v4l.org/RM7v8

Comment: @MarkusZeller Ok thanks. Looks good. In the fiddle, is there any way we can extract id and alt as well ?

Comment: Sure, just get the element with it's attributes. You also could use xpath if it is easier for you.